# Creating sub menu below toggle menu item for mobile versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I use the following code to create a toggle menu for mobile versions and It works fine but I want to generate a sub menu below a menu item. For example I want to have to create two sub tabs for **SERVICES** item like New and Used to be appeared only when the user clicks on **SERVICES**. Anybody can help me doing this?

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navigation">
<a class="menu_button" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">&#9776;  MENU</a>
<ul id="navigation_list" role="navigation">
<li><a href=#>HOME</a></li>
<li><a href=#>SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href=#>WORK</a></li>
<li><a href=#>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**Javascript**

```
var originalNavClasses;

function toggleNav() {
var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
var classes = elem.className;
if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
originalNavClasses = classes;
}
elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
}
```

From http://blog.g-design.net/post/42617934013/create-an-accessible-toggle-menu-for-mobile
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply just create another list inside of the SERVICES list item.  You can initially hide the list, and when you want to see it, via clicking, you just display it.

```
<nav id="navigation">
<a class="menu_button" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">&#9776;  MENU</a>
<ul id="navigation_list" role="navigation">
<li><a href=#>HOME</a></li>
<li id="services-item"><a href="#">SERVICES</a> 
    <ul id="sub_list" style="display: none;">
      <li>NEW</li> 
      <li>USED</li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
<li><a href=#>WORK</a></li>
<li><a href=#>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

If you want to see the list when you click SERVICES, you need to add javascript, or a JS library, to do so:

```
//jQuery
$('#services-item').on('click', function() {
    $('#sub-list').toggle();
)};
```

This method does not allow SERVICES to direct the user to a page.  If you need it to direct a user to a page, then just add an icon beside the SERVICES text that toggles the sub-list when clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this solution still doesn't work for me. Can we use hover for the mobile versions?

Comment: Ah, good point!  Not being able to hover on mobile completely slipped my mind.  In that case, I believe that you have two options:
1) Make it so SERVICES is not a link to a page, and expands and contracts the sub menu when clicked.
2) If you need SERVICES to be a link to a page, add a down arrow of sorts beside 'SERVICES' that expands and contracts when clicked.
Ill edit my answer to reflect this